# RabbitMq queue length returns 0

Tags: rabbitmq, signalr, .net-6.0

I'm working in a project of notifications service with .NET 6.0 using SignalR for the real-time.

I want to implement RabbitMq to store notifications in queue. I can send notifications, but I can't consume them from rabbit. What am I doing wrong?

Rabbit queues:

[image]

NotificationHub:

```
 public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
 {
     try
     {
         var token = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Query["access_token"];

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
         {
             var result = await UserConnectionAsync(token);
             await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).ConnectionResponse(result.response);

             if (result.succesfulConnection)
             {
                 await SendStoredNotifications(result.userId);
                 //await _rabbit.ConsumeMessages(result.userId);
             }
             else
             {
                 var response = new ServerResponse
                 {
                     status = "Rejected",
                     message = "Error en la autorizacion"
                 };
                 await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).ConnectionResponse(response);
                 Context.Abort();
             }
         }
         else
         {
             var response = new ServerResponse
             {
                 status = "Rejected",
                 message = "Token no proporcionado"
             };
             await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).ConnectionResponse(response);
             Context.Abort();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Error {ex.Message}");
         throw new Exception($"Error en la conexion {ex.Message}");
     }
 }
```

SendStoredNotifications:

```
  private async Task SendStoredNotifications(string userId)
  {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
      {
          //var notifications = _notificationStore.RetrieveNotifications(userId);
          var notifications = await _rabbit.ConsumeMessages(userId);

          foreach (var notification in notifications)
          {
              await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendNotification(notification);
          }

          _notificationStore.ClearNotifications(userId);
      }
  }
```

Here is from I create the connection to rabbitMq:

```
  public void CreateConnection()
  {
      try
      {
          var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
          {
              HostName = "localhost",
              UserName = "guest",
              Password = "guest",
              Port = 5672
          };
          _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          throw new BadHttpRequestException(ex.Message);
      }
  }
```

And this is the function where I consume notifications from rabbitMq, but it isn't working:

```
public async Task<List<NotificationModel>> ConsumeMessages(string userId)
{
    List<NotificationModel> messages = new List<NotificationModel>();

    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", UserName = "guest", Password = "guest", Port = 5672 };
    CreateConnection();

    if (_connection.IsOpen)
    {
        using var channel = _connection.CreateModel();
        channel.QueueDeclare("Notification", durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false);
        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                    var jsonMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                    var notification = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<NotificationUserId>(jsonMessage);

                    // Verifica si el ID de usuario coincide con el usuario especificado
                    if (notification.UserId == userId)
                    {
                        messages.Add(notification.Notification);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception("Erro deserializando el mensaje"); }
            };

        channel.BasicQos(0,prefetchCount: 1, global: false);
        var result = channel.BasicConsume(queue: "Notification", autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);

        _messageReceiveEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        channel.ModelShutdown += (model, reason) =>
            {
                _messageReceiveEvent.Set();
            };
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Connection closed");
    }

    return messages;
}
```

`messages.Count` is 0